# Wrong data coming out when curl from HBASE

Tags: rest, curl, hive, hbase

A table scan [scan 'mytable']from hbase shell(ssh putty) is showing me correct values

But if I give a command from ssh, 
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:54321/mytable/first/cf  - it shows all the cells but data is coming as junk. eg: "Zmlyc3Q=" instead of "first"
Note : I am using a hortonworks sandbox on a Vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything retrieved from the REST API (row key, family, column and value) is base64-encoded, you have to decode it.

Pseudo-code:

```
base64("first") == "Zmlyc3Q="
```